# how to conditionally select variables?

Tags: if-statement, sas

I have a table with 2 variables - X and Y.
I wish to conditionally select X OR Y, depending on the month, as such:

```
DATA test ;
    SET work.Final_union ;
    IF 1 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 5
    THEN output  ;
    IF 6 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 12
    THEN output ;
RUN ;
```

where do I put the selected variables?

Comment: Explain why.  Is it because you have MONTH coded into the NAME of the variable instead of storing MONTH as its own variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I suggest using a macro variable

So you want a different variables in your output depending on the day you run it.
you can use statements like `drop x;` or `keep y;`, but the problem is to make them time dependent. For that, I will put them in a macro variable.

### One way to do that is:

```
proc sql;
   select distinct case 
        when 1 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <=  5 THEN 'y';
        when 6 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 12 THEN 'x';
   end
   into :drop
   from SASHELP.CLASS;
quit;
```

I could use any dataset in stead of `SASHELP.CLASS`, but this is a small one that is always there.

### An alternative is:

```
data _null_;
   select ;
        when (1 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <=  5) call symput('drop', 'y');
        when (6 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 12) call symput('drop', 'x');
   end;
run;
quit;
```

macro variables are used at compile time, not at run time, but SAS compiles a stem, then runs it then compiles the next. Therefore a macro variable created in one step can be used in the next.

### Now you can use that with

```
DATA test ;
    SET work.Final_union ;
    drop &drop;
RUN ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`MONTH(TODAY())` is the month in which the program is running.

Suppose

- `X` is the variable of interest when running the code during Jan to May, and
- `Y` is the variable of interest when running the code during months June to December.

Your original code creates output that has both X and Y for all rows in the data set.

```
DATA test ;
    SET work.Final_union ;

    IF 1 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 5 THEN output;    /* all rows are output Jan to May */
    IF 6 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 12 THEN output ;  /* all rows are output Jun to Dec */
RUN ;
```

Since all rows are always output, change the code so that data set options for selecting variables is used (`keep=`*wanted variables*) or (`drop=`*unwanted variables)*.  Data set options are **not** programmatically modifiable during a running step, so the 'change the code' is going to be *generated code* that is resolved via the macro processor.

Example:

```
* code gen;
data _null_;
  if 1 <= month(today()) <= 5 
    then call symput ('my_codegen', 'keep=x');
    else call symput ('my_codegen', 'keep=y');
run;

/* the macro symbol named 'my_codegen' now contains program source code
 * that can be resolved (by prefixing the symbol with ampersand) in this 
 * subsequent step 
 */

data want;
  set have (&my_codegen);
run;
```

In the months Jan to May the actual code submitted will be

```
 set have(keep=X);
```

and for June to December

```
  set have(keep=Y);
```

**Caveat**

Such a data processing manipulation causes mostly headaches in any downstream programming.  Why ?  Because all the inputs will be variant according the month of submit (run) time.  If you run the same reports through out the year, but for different variables, a better data transformation would be

```
data have;
    IF 1 <= MONTH(TODAY()) <= 5 THEN DO;
      RESULT_VAR = 'X';
      RESULT = X;
    END;
    ELSE DO;
      RESULT_VAR = 'Y';
      RESULT = Y;
    END;
run;

...
 downstream code does not need to muck around with macro symbols
 or multiple versions, one version using X and one version using Y
...

Proc XYZZY data=have;
  BY RESULT_VAR;
  VAR RESULT;
run;
```